# Need WordPress short code for post in div instead of ul

Tags: php, wordpress, customization

[image]

I want my post using Div instead of ul.My post are displaying in ul at the moment.Is there any way to change ul into Div ?

Comment: What code are you using to display this and where is it being called? We can't help you change code if you don't show us the code that needs to be changed!

Comment: @FluffyKitten sorry ..this is the code: [display-posts posts_per_page="1" include_excerpt="false" excerpt_length="0" offset="2"]

Comment: That is to do with the functionality of the shortcode you are using. This isn't a programming question, so it is off topic for Stack Overflow. Check the documentation for the shortcode to see if there is an option to change this, or ask on the plugin support forum.

Comment: ok I will look into it now. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using this plugin: https://it.wordpress.org/plugins/display-posts-shortcode/ it seems that you can use the 'wrapper' attribute of your shortcode.

So let it be like:

```
 [display-posts posts_per_page="1" include_excerpt="false" excerpt_length="0" offset="2" wrapper="div"]
```